# CodeDom to generate VB.NET operator overload?

Tags: vb.net, operator-overloading, codedom

Is there a way to use CodeDom to generate an overloaded operator in Vb.net? I want to generate this:

```
Public Shared Operator =(ByVal x As MyType, ByVal y As MyType) As Boolean
  Return x Is y
End Operator
```

The closest hack I can think of to do this the following:

```
Dim eq As New CodeMemberMethod()
eq.Name = "Operator ="
eq.Parameters.Add(New CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(New CodeTypeReference("MyType"), "x"))
eq.Parameters.Add(New CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(New CodeTypeReference("MyType"), "y"))
eq.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public Or MemberAttributes.Static
eq.ReturnType = New CodeTypeReference(GetType(Boolean))
eq.Statements.Add(New CodeMethodReturnStatement(New CodeBinaryOperatorExpression(New CodeVariableReferenceExpression("x"), CodeBinaryOperatorType.IdentityEquality, New CodeVariableReferenceExpression("y"))))
type.Members.Add(eq)
```

Which generates this, close but obviously wrong:

```
Public Shared Function Operator =(ByVal x As MyType, ByVal y As MyType) As Boolean
    Return (x Is y)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate this solution, but it works.

```
Dim eq As New CodeSnippetTypeMember("Public Shared Operator =(ByVal x As MyType, ByVal y As MyType) As Boolean" & Environment.NewLine & "Return x Is y" & Environment.NewLine & "End Operator")
type.Members.Add(eq)
```

I'm sure the correct way has something to do with inheriting from CodeTypeMember to define the member, then inheriting from Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeGenerator to provide the implementation of the member, but I don't have the time to deal with all that. I think it's time to make a switch from CodeDom to T4.

Comment: I hate that too but it's the quickest to get there.